# Mustering in port territories

Tags: game-of-thrones

Could I get a comprehensive clarification of the rules surrounding mustering and supply limits in territories that have ports?

My understanding is:

- When mustering, all territories (whether land, port, or sea) must adhere to supply limits.
- When mustering at a Castle/Stronghold territory with a port, units can be placed in either the land, the port, or adjacent sea territory.

Is my understanding of these rules correct?

What it seems is that a player could keep a single infantry on their Castle/Stronghold territory, and because they have *two* adjacent territories (the port, and the sea) they can muster into, it makes it possible for them continually muster every turn, using the special consolidate power token.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. However remember that as soon as you have two or more ships in the same area (port or sea), they are considered an army and must adhere to supply limits.

Obviously if you muster into both the port and sea you're potentially blocking your port ship for being able to move out into the sea. That makes your castle/stronghold a ripe target for attack as if an enemy were to defeat that one footman, any boats in port would be replaced by an equal number of your enemy's ships (pg.25).

Something else to note: The special Consolidate Power token **must** be placed on the castle/stronghold in order to muster. You are not allowed to muster by placing the special Consolidate Power token on the port space.

Comment: Wait, to clarify, if you capture a territory with a port, you _capture_ the ships?!

Comment: If there are ships in the port, yes